# como faço para fazer um upload de um arquivo em php fazendo um replace do arquivo existente?

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso fazer um upload de um arquivo porém esse arquivo vai ter o mesmo nome só que com conteúdo diferente, tenho o código abaixo que faz esse upload do arquivo só que quando eu coloco um arquivo diferente com o mesmo nome ele não o substitui alguém poderia ver o que estou fazendo de errado

aqui eu tenho o html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

código php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

header("location:upload.php");
?>
```

Comment: Poderia melhorar seu código, coloque-o dentro de tag <pre></pre> e com quebra de linha por gentileza.

Comment: `// Check if file already exists` apenas delete essa parte.

Answer (score 3):

Esse bloco de código impede que um arquivo com um nome já existente seja sobrescrito, ele define zero para `$uploadOk` que mais tarde é comparado e caso seja zero cancela a ação `if ($uploadOk == 0) {`.

Para resolver o problema basta remover ele.

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: obrigado era isso mesmo

Comment: @derekjupter vc pode marcar a resposta como aceita com aquele sinal verde em baixo dos votos, assim outros que tiverem uma duvida parecida irão saber que o problema foi solucionado.